# Correct use of passive and active gerund

Tags: gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund, active-vs-passive

Please consider the question from a grammar test.

I don't mind ______ that I'm wrong.

1. **being told**
2. telling
3. to tell
4. to be told

The test says (1) option is correct. My point is that both (1) and (2) options are correct:

1. I don't mind being told that I'm wrong. (= I have nothing against the fact that someone tells me I'm wrong. Either I don't care about it or use it to make myself better.)
2. I don't mind telling that I'm wrong. (= I am able to confess that I am/was wrong at something. *e.g. I told my boss that I was wrong in a conversation with a client.* )

Thank you!

Comment: _I don't mind telling that I'm wrong_ is not idiomatic English. _Telling_ needs an object - _I don't mind telling you_ - or we would use _admitting_ instead.

Comment: ""Telling" requires a direct object, as in I don't mind him telling me that I'm wrong". The alternative would be to replace "telling" with intransitive "saying", as in "I don't mind saying that I'm wrong".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "tell" normally takes an indirect object. If your sentence were

> I don't mind telling **him** that I'm wrong.

then "telling" would be allowable, but in your example, only 1. is correct.

> [Cambridge Dictionary "say/tell"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/say-or-tell)
> "tell normally takes an indirect object (one or more people = IO) and a direct object (the reported clause = DO):
> The boy told [IO]us [DO]he didn’t want any money.

As the linked article above points out, "tell" can be used without an indirect object if the direct object is in a limited set of words, including "story", "lie", and some others, but with a clause, such as "that I'm wrong", it requires an indirect object.

(There is an exception for a completely different sense of "tell" that means "detect":
"I can tell that it's right."
In that case, the clause is the direct object, but an indirect object can't be used because of the meaning of "tell".)